# ReactJs : Nested State Not getting Updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have below code :

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
const iState ={
    Name : '',
    Email :'',
    Salary :0,
    Error:{
        EName:'*',
        EEmail:'*',
        ESalary:'*'
    }

}
function ReactForm() {
    
const [state, setstate] = useState(iState);
    function validationHandler(e)
    {        
        switch (e.target.name) {
            
            case 'txtName':
                console.log(e.target.value);
                if(e.target.value=='')
                {
                    console.log('inside condition')
                    setstate({...state.Error, EName:'Value Cannot be blank'})
                    console.log(state);
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log('inside else condition')
                    setstate({...state, EName:''})
                }
                setstate({...state, Name:e.target.value})
                break;
                case 'txtEmail':
                setstate({...state, Email:e.target.value})
                break;
                case 'txtSalary':
                setstate({...state, Salary:e.target.value})
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        
        console.log(state);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            Name : <input name="txtName" type="text" onChange={(e)=>validationHandler(e)}></input>
            <label> {state.Error.EName==undefined ? '*':state.Error.EName} </label>
            <br></br>            
            Email : <input name="txtEmail" type="text" onChange={(e)=>validationHandler(e)}></input>
            <br></br>            
            Salary : <input name="txtSalary" type="text" onChange={(e)=>validationHandler(e)}></input>
            <br></br>
            <button onClick={validationHandler}>Validate Us</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ReactForm
```

In this, iState has Error portion nested within -

```
const iState ={
        Name : '',
        Email :'',
        Salary :0,
        Error:{
            EName:'*',
            EEmail:'*',
            ESalary:'*'
        }    
    }
```

When I am trying to update the nested state of Error , its not getting updated -

```
if(e.target.value=='')
                    {
                        console.log('inside condition')
                        setstate({...state.Error, EName:'Value Cannot be blank'})
                        console.log(state);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log('inside else condition')
                        setstate({...state, EName:''})
                    }
```

I can see it entering within else block , but not updating the state.
I also tried with - `setstate({...state.Error, EName:''})`

**EDIT 1 :**

```
if(e.target.value=='')
                {
                    console.log('inside condition')
                    setstate({ ...state, Error: { ...state.Error, Ename: 'Value Cannot be blank' }})
                    console.log(state);
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log('inside else condition')
                    setstate({ ...state, Error: { ...state.Error, Ename: 'Value Cannot be blank' }})
                }
```

Setting state changed  -`setstate({ ...state, Error: { ...state.Error, Ename: 'Value Cannot be blank' }})`

Still state not getting updated -

[image]

Comment: If you care for a little suggestion, I would refactor this code to be a bit less centralised in a single function. Right now, this `validationHandler` is doing too much and even detecting the field by the name of the event target, when a more "React-ish" way of doing that would be to have different updaters triggered by each field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `this.setState` in class components, state setter function returned by the `useState` hook does not merges the old state with the new state - you need to do it yourself. Not doing this will overwrite the existing state.

Currently you are overwriting the existing state. Correct way to update the state is shown below:

This

```
setstate({...state.Error, EName:'Value Cannot be blank'})
```

should be

```
setstate({ ...state, Error: { ...state.Error, Ename: 'Value Cannot be blank' } })
```

**Explanation of why this works:**

First you *spread* the top level state object in the newly created object passed to `setState`. After that you add `Error` key and its value is another object in which you *spread* `state.Error`. Finally, you add a `Ename` key in the nested object and set its value.

Above steps re-create a new object with the similar structure as the initial state object.

Similarly this

```
setstate({...state, EName:''})
```

should be

```
setstate({...state, Error: { ...state.Error, EName:'' } })
```

#### Edit

Please note that state is updated asynchronously and it is constant within a particular render of a component.

This means that logging the state immediately after calling the state setter function will log the old state. Component can only see the updated state *after* it has re-rendered.

To log the updated state, use the `useEffect` hook as shown below:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(state);
}, [state]);
```

This will log the updated state because it will execute:

- after the initial render
- every time component re-renders as a result of `state` update.

Comment: Could you please check EDIT 1 ? I have changed the method to set state but state not getting updated.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use the previous state directly while setting the new state as state changes are asynchronous.

```
setState((prevState)=>{...prevState, Error: { ...prevState.Error, EName:'Value Cannot be blank' }})
```

Comment: previous state matters only if the new state is updated based on the previous state value like incrementing a counter. In OP's case, previous state doesn't matters. Having said that, its not wrong to update the state using the previous state.

Comment: @Yousaf Aren't we using the Error object from previous state while updating the new state? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: In functional component, state is always updated like this. What i meant by _depending on the previous state_ is that new state depends on the old value like incrementing a counter. Incrementing a counter takes the old value and then adds 1 into it.  In OP's case, we are overwriting the value of the `Ename` key. But as i mentioned before, using the previous state is not wrong here, it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You should make it like this

```
setstate({...state, Error: { ...state.Error, EName:'Value Cannot be blank' }})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use spread current state and update the nested vaues

```
setState( previous => {...previous, Error: { ...previous.Error, EName:'Value Cannot be blank'} })
```